# Align cell widget in center within QTableWidget?

Tags: qt4, qtablewidget, qt4.7

How can I align my table widget items in center ? My first column was a `QCheckBox` , but I checked documents , seems you can only set alignment for `QTableWidgetItem` , not the cell widget inside.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting model to your TableWidget (with **data** virtual implementation) I think will help.
**QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const [pure virtual]** and return the needed alignment if role is an alignment.